# Does the effect of Shatter Shock in SWTOR multiply if I use it more than once in a 45 second window?

Tags: star-wars-the-old-republic

I've noticed that my agent in SWTOR has the Shatter Shot ability which has the following description:

> Fires a high-impact shot that deals 754 - 809 weapon damage and
>   reduces the target's armor by 20% for 45 seconds. Additionally
>   inflicts trauma for 9 seconds, reducing all healing the target
>   receives by 20%.

Does that mean that if it fire it 3 times in 45 seconds, my target's armor will reduce by 60% and my target's healing will be reduced by 60%?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it does not.  If you use the ability again before the debuff expires, it simply refreshes the duration of the debuff.

It also does not stack with other armor or trauma debuffs applied by other players — the "best" one is the only one that counts.